# Installing python packages without dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to install a specific version of a python package into a pre-installed python environment. The package is [laspy](https://github.com/laspy/laspy) and the version is an old one (1.2.5). The package is supposed to work with Python version 2.7, but I am trying to install it against version 3.5, as I saw [here](https://github.com/laspy/laspy/issues/40) that it should work on Python 3.4.

The real reason why I am doing so is that this specific Python is shipped with [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/installing-python-for-arcgis-pro.htm), and I need the `arcpy` module which is present only in this installation.

I've been able to download the `laspy` package using `pip download`. This module depends on the module `numpy`, which is already present in the Python environment. This is causing the `pip install` to fail with error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accesso negato: 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\Pro\\bin\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy'
```

which I kind of understand (it cannot overwrite the already installed `numpy`).

Here comes my big doubt: would installing `laspy` with `pip` and `--no-dependencies` option "break" my python installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So stupid... The error message `PermissionError` was just because I opened cmd without administrative privileges...

Just installed `laspy` with `pip install laspy==1.2.5`. Hopefully it will work with this 64bit version of Python shipped with ArcGIS Pro (I was actually using it with the python 2.7 shipped with ArcGIS 10.x but it's 32bit and with LAS files it is easy to receive "out of memory" messages...).

Will edit this answer to give some news on the compatibility.

**UPDATE**

Seems like I was just able to import laspy, but all other submodules of it didn't work...

e.g. `import laspy` works 'from laspy.File import file' throws `No module named 'laspy.File'`.

I am now switching to a fork ([this one](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/laspy)), which should be compatible hopefully.